# WKWebView editable with .xlf, .html files

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am showing .html and .xlf files in

> WKWebView

and it is working fine.

I made WebView to edit content but i am not sure how to save the edited content.

I mean i have long text, and when i edit i want to save it exactly what we entered.

I implemented code as mentioned below

https://codeburst.io/rich-text-editor-for-ios-using-wkwebview-440d88d73bbf

Please let me know how to save edited text in

> WKWebView

.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Access the content with javascript like  `document.querySelector('#editor').innerHTML` over WKWebViews `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Javascript section of reference you mentioned. Then you need implement the delegate method for WKScriptMessageHandler as below,

```
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if (message.name == "textDidChange") {
        print(message.body)//This will be HTML data
    }
}
```

Comment: I already implemented it, but this method is not getting called.

Comment: Can you add your source code in the question?

Comment: i added new question here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67331399/editable-wkwebview . I guess this has lot of information there. I will add bounty to that question after 2 days.