# Editable WKWebView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am displaying .html and .xml files in WKWebView.
I am concatenating all the data and displaying below string in WKWevView

```
sourceWebView.loadHTMLString(sourceHtmlStr, baseURL: nil)
```

I made my webview as editable using below, after loading the content i.e in

> webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){}

```
singleWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.setAttribute('contentEditable','true')") { (anyObj: Any?, error: Error?) in
   if anyObj != nil{
       print("AnyObj in jave script : \(anyObj!)")
   }
   if error != nil{
       print("Error in Java script : \(error!)")
   }
}
```

Above code made the WKWebView as editable. But i am not sure how to save the edited values.
I followed [Link](https://codeburst.io/rich-text-editor-for-ios-using-wkwebview-440d88d73bbf)  and used below code

i have below code in .js file

```
var richeditor = {};
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");

richeditor.insertText = function(text) {
    editor.innerHTML = text;
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.heightDidChange.postMessage(document.body.offsetHeight);
}

editor.addEventListener("input", function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.textDidChange.postMessage(editor.innerHTML);
}, false)

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.heightDidChange.postMessage(document.body.offsetHeight);
}, false);
```

in WindowDidLoad:

```
guard let scriptPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RichTextEditor", ofType: "js"),
   let scriptContent = try? String(contentsOfFile: scriptPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
else {
   print("Unable to find javscript for text editor")
   return
}
singleWebView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: scriptContent, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))

let configuration = singleWebView.configuration
[ShowPreviewWindowContoller.textDidChange, ShowPreviewWindowContoller.heightDidChange].forEach {
   configuration.userContentController.add(WeakScriptMessageHandler(delegate: self), name: $0)
}
```

and added below method :

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
   switch message.name {
   case ShowPreviewWindowContoller.textDidChange:
       guard let body = message.body as? String else { return }
       delegate?.textDidChange(text: body)
   case ShowPreviewWindowContoller.heightDidChange:
       guard let height = message.body as? CGFloat else { return }
       self.height = height > ShowPreviewWindowContoller.defaultHeight ? height + 30 : ShowPreviewWindowContoller.defaultHeight
       delegate?.heightDidChange()
    default:
       break
    }
}
```

This way of implementation is not saving the edited data.

Also to note here is i don't have "editor" element in the html string.
i am not  really sure what all elements the html string has as the file is not a constant one, elements can be anything.

Sorry for the long question.
Please let me know on how to implement this.
Editing WKWebView, saving the edited text back.
Also i will be having lot of strings like below, i need to make sure i replace into exact element

```
<trans-unit id="0000000006" datatype="x-text/xml" restype="string">
    <target>Some Text here</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="0000000007" datatype="x-text/xml" restype="string">
    <target>Some Text here</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I am using below HTML string, Please note i really don't have any control on html, i display what ever user selects.

Edit : Added modified htmlstring

```
<!doctype html>\n
<html>
   \n
   <head>
      \n
      <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
      \n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"AppleCare Training authored this course. If you use this course outside the AppleCare Training site, give credit to its author.\">\n<!-- If you are using an interaction to mark the page complete or if it is an AA page, change mark_complete to false -->\n
      <meta name=\"template_version\" content=\"01.05.2015\">
      \n
      <meta name=\"page\" content=\" \" mark_complete=\"false\">
      \n
      <link href=\"https://idesk.corp.apple.com/training/ce/_common/css/sgt.css\" media=\"screen, projection\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/>
      \n<script>\n\tvar url = window.location.href;\n\tvar filename = \"\";\n\tvar is_local = url.substr(0,4);\n\tif(is_local==\"file\" || window.location.hostname === \"localhost\"){\n\t\t//Local Common Folder Location\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost/_common/js/jquery.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost/_common/js/ready.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t}else{\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/training/ce/_common/js/jquery.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/training/ce/_common/js/ready.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t}\n</script>\n\n
      <title>
         <target id=2>Key Terms and Concepts</target>
      </title>
      \n
   </head>
   \n\n
   <body class=\"aa\">
      \n\n\t\t\t<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->\n\t
      <div id=\"maincontent\">
         \n
         <div id=\"learningcontentdiv\">
            \n
            <div id=\"morelearningcontentdiv\"></div>
            \n
         </div>
         \n\t\t\t  
         <div id=\"content\">
            \n
            <div id=\"close_aa_term\">
               <target id=4>×</target>
            </div>
            \n
            <h2>
               <target id=6>Key Terms and Concepts</target>
            </h2>
            \n
            <p>
               <target id=8>You should already be familiar with all the terms in this module.</target>
               \t  
            </p>
            \n\t  
         </div>
         \n
      </div>
      \n\n<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->\n
   </body>
   \n
</html>
```

Comment: Is this question the same question? [WKWebView editable with .xlf, .html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284462/wkwebview-editable-with-xlf-html-files)

Comment: @Willeke , yes i voted to delete the other question. I provided more information here.

Comment: The other question already has answers and a bounty. Please edit the other question and delete this question.

Comment: @Willeke , i already marked other one as delete, i am afraid if i mark this delete then both my questions will be deleted. Not sure how it works in Stack overflow.

Comment: @Willeke i closed the other question, fyi i gave bounty to the one who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with this sample code works as expected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

var htmlString = """

<!doctype html>\n
<html>
   \n
   <head>
      \n
      <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
      \n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"AppleCare Training authored this course. If you use this course outside the AppleCare Training site, give credit to its author.\">\n<!-- If you are using an interaction to mark the page complete or if it is an AA page, change mark_complete to false -->\n
      <meta name=\"template_version\" content=\"01.05.2015\">
      \n
      <meta name=\"page\" content=\" \" mark_complete=\"false\">
      \n
      <link href=\"https://idesk.corp.apple.com/training/ce/_common/css/sgt.css\" media=\"screen, projection\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/>
      \n<script>\n\tvar url = window.location.href;\n\tvar filename = \"\";\n\tvar is_local = url.substr(0,4);\n\tif(is_local==\"file\" || window.location.hostname === \"localhost\"){\n\t\t//Local Common Folder Location\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost/_common/js/jquery.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost/_common/js/ready.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t}else{\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/training/ce/_common/js/jquery.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t\tdocument.write(\'\\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/training/ce/_common/js/ready.js\">\\x3C/script>\');\n\t}\n</script>\n\n
      <title>
         <target id=2>Key Terms and Concepts</target>
      </title>
      \n
   </head>
   \n\n
   <body class=\"aa\">
      \n\n\t\t\t<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->\n\t
      <div id=\"maincontent\">
         \n
         <div id=\"learningcontentdiv\">
            \n
            <div id=\"morelearningcontentdiv\"></div>
            \n
         </div>
         \n\t\t\t
         <div id=\"content\">
            \n
            <div id=\"close_aa_term\">
               <target id=4>×</target>
            </div>
            \n
            <h2>
               <target id=6>Key Terms and Concepts</target>
            </h2>
            \n
            <p>
               <target id=8>You should already be familiar with all the terms in this module.</target>
               \t
            </p>
            \n\t
         </div>
         \n
      </div>
      \n\n<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->\n
   </body>
   \n
</html>
"""

var javaScript = """
var richeditor = {};
var editor = document.body;

function getActiveDiv() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var node = document.createElement('span');
    range.insertNode(node);
    range = range.cloneRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    range.collapse(false);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    var activeDiv = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    return activeDiv;
}

richeditor.insertText = function(text) {
    editor.innerHTML = text;
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.heightDidChange.postMessage(document.body.offsetHeight);
}

editor.addEventListener("input", function() {
var activeElement = getActiveDiv()
window.webkit.messageHandlers.textDidChange.postMessage("activeElement ID = "+ activeElement.id + " and TEXT = " + activeElement.innerHTML);
}, false)

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.heightDidChange.postMessage(document.body.offsetHeight);
}, false);

"""



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "heightDidChange")
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "textDidChange")
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: javaScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400), configuration: config)

    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    
  }


  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.name)
    let body = message.body
    print(body)
  }
    

}

extension ViewController : WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){
      webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.setAttribute('contentEditable','true')") { (anyObj: Any?, error: Error?) in
         if anyObj != nil{
             print("AnyObj in jave script : \(anyObj!)")
         }
         if error != nil{
             print("Error in Java script : \(error!)")
         }
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Some how this is not working for me. But as i mentioned in my long question, my html string don't have any editor element. I am posting my html string in the question. (i can't add here)

Comment: Updated code to work as per html mentioned in the question.

Comment: WOW thank you for the answer. It is working perfectly. But i edited the htmlstring and added in my question. In the html string i added tags <target> with ID's. Each string has some ids. Can we exactly in which Target element user is editing?

Comment: You can addEventListener for each separately.

Comment: you mean in the .js file? But here we don't know the target id's. Everything should be done programatically.

Comment: Used solution mentioned in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093285/how-do-i-get-the-element-being-edited to find the active element.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and this is working fine.
I just changed below code in the java script, instead of sending id and text as one string, i changed it to pass dictionary. It is working fine. 
window.webkit.messageHandlers.textDidChange.postMessage({"Element ID" : activeElement.id, "Text" : activeElement.innerHTML});